# Find an example of two disjonit sets $A$ and $B$ of real numbers such that $m^{*}(A \cup B) < m^{*}(A) + m^{*}(B)$.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

**Theorem:** For any two sets $A$ and $B$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, we have
$$m^{*}(A \cup B) \le m^{*}(A) + m^{*}(B).$$

Moreover, I can show that there exist two disjoint sets $A$ and $B$ such that
$$m^{*}(A \cup B) < m^{*}(A) + m^{*}(B)$$
by using the contradiction to show that every set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is measurable (this is unreasonable since the Vitali set is a non-measurable set in $\mathbb{R}^n$)

My question is whether we can find the form of any two sets like this? The form of them is trivial?

Comment: could you report the definition of $m^*$?

Comment: Are you looking for just *one* example of two such sets? Or on the other hand are you looking for all such pairs of sets? [I ask because the term "any" is (to me) ambiguous here.]

Comment: @Exodd Sorry, I forgot to mention what $m^*$ is. In this problem, $m^*$ is a Lebesgue outer measure.

Comment: @coffeemath Oh, I am looking for just such a pair of sets. But I am very happy if you can help me to see if there is more than just one pair.

Comment: @TungNguyen Play with Vitali set to find another example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Outer measure does not satisfy countable additivity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4391575/outer-measure-does-not-satisfy-countable-additivity)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know outer measure restricted to Lebesgue sigma algebra is countably additive.

If $A, B$ are disjoint measurable sets then $m^*(A\cup B) =m^*(A) +m^*(B) $

Hence for disjoint measurable sets strictly sub-aditivity of Lebesgue outer measure is not possible.

---

To get strictly sub-aditivity of outer measure choose $B\subset [0, 1]$ a [Bernstein set](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_set) .

Then Bernstein sets are non measurable and has full outer measure. Complement of a Bernstein is also Bernstein.

Then

$m^*(B\cup B^c)=m^*([0,1])=1<2=m^*(B) +m^*(B^c) $